# Unable to access ingress IP in k3s using Lima or k3d on Mac M1

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, apple-m1, k3s, k3d

I'm trying to set up a Kubernetes cluster on my Mac M1 using k3s and either Lima or k3d with Rancher. I have successfully deployed my application and created an ingress, but I'm having trouble accessing it. The ingress appears to be generated with an IP address of 192.168.5.15, but when I try to ping or curl it, I get a timeout error.

I'm not sure what I might be missing or doing wrong. Has anyone else experienced this issue, or does anyone have any suggestions on what I can try to resolve it? I appreciate any help or insights you can provide. Thank you!

Here is my setup:

backend-ingress.yml file

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
name: backend-ingress
namespace: default
spec:
rules:

- http:
  paths:
  - path: /api
    pathType: Prefix
    backend:
    service:
    name: appbackend
    port:
    number: 8080
```

frontend-ingress.yml file

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontend-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: appfrontend
            port:
              number: 9000
```

[Ping from local to ingress IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgzTD.png)